# I want use different kernels on jupyter, but how can I install different libraries on different kernel?

Tags: python, jupyter

I have two kernels on my jupyter, one is py2.7 and the other is py3.5, but how can I install different libraries like pandas or numpy for py2.7?

Answer (score 1):

You ought to use a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/): this create a local copy of the Python of your choice.

Then you can use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to install libraries like Pandas…

But, before, install Jupyter in your newly created virtualenv with:

```
pip install jupyter
```